java.lang.SecurityException: iccOpenLogicalChannel
I want to run applet that is installed on sim card using android app and receive results. so i tried Telephony API and OMAPI but I catch "java.lang.SecurityException" when i try to create logical channel. And I need a normal application or a way to install my app without rooting my phone.
i tried to run apdu command using Telephony API on sim card using AID that I gave to it. I added "android.hardware.telephony" and user permission "android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE". I also tried omapi and got security exception there neither when i tried to create logical channel.

And i don't want to use OTA for running APDU commands
